# How do we do network operation on receiving userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

If the didReceiveNotificationResponse method execution is completed and the completion handler is not called, the app will be moved to suspended state unlike application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: callback where ios waits for 30 seconds before suspending the app. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Try to post some code when you ask a question, it increases the chances of getting answered.

Comment: `beginBackgroundTaskEithExpirarionHandler`